# Change the style of the item in rectjs and remove it if I clicked another item

Tags: css, reactjs

I wanted to change the style of an item with one click in a list and remove it if I click another item
I did like this but when I click on the second it doesn’t change to the first

```
const ref = useRef();

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (ref.current.style.backgroundColor) {
      ref.current.style.backgroundColor = '';
      ref.current.style.color = '';
    } else {
      ref.current.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      ref.current.style.color = 'white';
    }
  };



 <Card ref={ref} elevation={6} style={{ marginBottom: "5px"}}  onClick={()=>{ handleClick()}} >
      <CardContent style={{ height: "10px" }}>
        <Typography >
          {user}
        </Typography>
     
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

any help please!

Comment: You are asking for bugs by changing styles directly on the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using a package like [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) ( `yarn add classnames` or `npm i classnames`) to apply conditional styling through classes rather than having to inline the element's styling directly.

You could pass the selected attribute to your Card component using React's [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) (or [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)) and then apply conditional styling to selected cards (i.e. `<Card selected />`).

Component.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Card from './Card';

const Component = () => {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

  const items = useSelector(state => state.items);

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setSelectedId(id);
  };

 return items.map(({id}) => 
   <Card
     key={id}
     onClick={() => handleClick(id)}
     selected={id === selectedId}
   >
      ...
   </Card>
 );
};

export default Component;
```

Card.js

```
import { classNames } from 'classnames';

const Card = ({ children, onClick, selected = false }) => (
  <div
    className={
      classNames('Card', {
        'Card--Selected': selected
      })
    }
    onClick={onClick}
  >
    { children }
  </div>
);

export default Card;
```

Card.scss

```
.Card {
  // Card styling...
    
  &--Selected {
    // Selected card styling...
  }
}
```